# Is it safe to use a global variable in other translation units if it is created by 'new' at global scope?

Tags: c++, global-variables

A global object is not safe to be used in other translation units because its initialization order is not defined. But global scope `new` has to be called before `main()`.

Is it safe to use a global variable in other translation units if it is created by `new` at global scope?

a.cpp

```
struct Point {
  int a;
  int b;
};

Point* p = new Point();
```

b.cpp

```
extern class Point* p;

int main() {
  // Can I use p safely here ?
}
```

Comment: Yes, `p` will point to a zero-initialized object of type `Point` when `main` starts execution. (The initialization of `p` could throw an `std::bad_alloc` exception and terminate the program though, although that is not very realistic.) But why would you want this instead of just `Point p;`? Also, since you only forward-declared `Point` in `b.cpp` you will not actually be able to access any member of `*p` in `main`.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have a misunderstanding about the global initialization order issue. `Point p;` or `Point p{};` works just as well. That variable would be zero-initialized before `main` is entered as well. It is only an issue if there are multiple globals referring to one another in their initialization.

Comment: Depends on what you try to do with `p`.  Right now b.cpp does not have a full definition of `Point` and cannot interact with it as anything but a pointer to an opaque type. You cannot `p->a` because b.cpp has no way of knowing that `Point::a` exists.

Comment: Re: "... global scope `new` has to be called before `main()`" -- true, but all global objects have to be constructed before entry into `main()`, so this isn't any different. The key is that the `new` is initializing the global scope object `p`. There's no magic here; you have to understand the rules about initialization of global objects.

Comment: That comment in `main` asks whether `p` can be safely used inside `main`. It can. As can **every** object defined in global scope.

Comment: @PeteBecker It means that heap memory can be allocated before main() starts. This is very interesting to me.

Comment: @user17732522 I just want to know if heap can be allocated for global object safely. Above example is just for test.

Comment: @user17732522 And as far as I know, if I use Point p; in global scope, It is not safe to use in another translation unit, even if it is not reference to other global object. Am I wrong?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa You can allocate memory in a global's initializer just as normally in an initializer of any other variable. But there is no difference between `Point p{};` and `Point* p = new Point{};`. Both will be initialized properly before `main` is entered. If they are used before `main` is entered, then you may not know whether they have been initialized before the use depending on multiple factors such as the translation unit in which the variable is defined and used. That applies exactly equally to both cases.

Comment: In fact, `Point* p = new Point{};` is more likely to cause problems, because it can never be _constant initialization_ evaluated at compile-time. Global variables with constant initialization don't have the initialization order issues at all, since they are initialized before any of the _dynamic initialization_ happens.

Comment: You're missing my point. Don't get hung up on heap allocation; it's a distraction. **Every** global object gets constructed before entry into `main`. Doesn't matter whether it's `Point p;` or `Point *p = new Point;`. Both will be fully created and usable inside `main`. The problem with initialization order is about using things from one translation unit in another translation unit **before** `main` has started, i.e., inside the constructor for some global object.